# Observational Equivalence of open terms in PCF

Tags: pl.programming-languages, functional-programming, semantics, denotational-semantics, typed-lambda-calculus

The notion of observational equivalence is rather intuitive, but formally I'm having some doubts in the particular case of open terms.

Lets consider the simple case where  the terms `M` and `N` are free variables, `M = x` and `N = y`. Choosing the program context `C[-] = (λxy.[-]) v w` we have,
`C[M] = (λxy.x) v w →* v`
`C[N] = (λxy.y) v w →* w`
So by definition `M` and `N` wouldn't be observationally equivalent.

However, consider any *adequate* denotational semantics of PCF. Then by definition of adequacy, `⟦M⟧ = ⟦N⟧` implies `M` and `N` observationally equivalent. The denotations of both (open) terms are,
`⟦M⟧ = ⟦x ⊢ x⟧ = id`
`⟦N⟧ = ⟦y ⊢ y⟧ = id`
From what we conclude `M` and `N`  to be observationally equivalent.

So, surely I must be going wrong somewhere, and I suspect it to be some trivial mistake. But where?

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer, thanks to jonsterling on reddit for the insight.

The error is that both `M` and `N` written as full judgements, must be weakened to have the same environment, and one that fits `C[-]`. So the question becomes whether  `⟦M⟧ = ⟦x,y ⊢ x⟧` and `⟦N⟧ = ⟦x,y ⊢ y⟧` are observationally equivalent.  And the contradiction above disappears.